# Search using ramda functions in object

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have the following code:

```
const trimString = (s) => s.trim()
const compareObjects = (o1, o2) => equals(o1, o2)
const itemExists = (haystack, needle) => contains(haystack, needle)

const objects = [
  { duration: '0.360000', name: 'Arthur', time: '0.660000',   paragraph: 'p0-0' },
  { duration: '0.150000', name: 'the',    time: '1.020000',   paragraph: 'p0-0' },
  { duration: '0.380000', name: 'rat',    time: '1.170000',   paragraph: 'p0-0' },
  { duration: '0.770000', name: '.',      time: '1.550000',   paragraph: 'p0-0' },
  { duration: '0.360000', name: 'Arthur', time: '89.820000',  paragraph: 'p1-0' },
  { duration: '0.390000', name: 'stood',  time: '90.180000',  paragraph: 'p1-0' },
  { duration: '0.090000', name: 'and',    time: '90.570000',  paragraph: 'p1-0' }
];

function searchFor(toSearch) {
  var results = [];
  toSearch = trimString(toSearch); // trim it
  for(var i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
    for(var key in objects[i]) {
      if(objects[i][key].indexOf(toSearch)!=-1) {
        if(!itemExists(results, objects[i])) results.push(objects[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return results;
}

log(searchFor('Arthur'))
```

I get the result:

```
[
    {
        duration: '0.360000',
        name: 'Arthur',
        time: '0.660000',
        paragraph: 'p0-0'
    },
    {
        duration: '0.360000',
        name: 'Arthur',
        time: '89.820000',
        paragraph: 'p1-0'
    }
]
```

But I am stuck on how to make this into a ramda function and able to add multiple search items and show the result only for `p0-0` if I used `Arthur the`

Any advise is much appreciated.

Comment: The requirements are a bit unclear to me.  Do you really want to search on *every* property of the objects?  That is, even though `{... time: '1.550000', ...}` is the only one with `'.'` in its name, if you searched for `'.'`, would you expect to retrieve every record since every duration and time includes them?

Comment: And then it's also not clear if "Arthur rat" would match your first paragraph, or only consecutive terms such as "Arthur", "Arthur the", "Arthur the rat", or "the rat"

Comment: Also, it looks as though [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) would do to replace you `trimString` function and [`R.equals`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#equals), although somewhat more powerful, would probably serve for your `compareObjects`, given your data.

Comment: And [`R.contains`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#contains) would probably do what `itemExists` does, although its parameters are in the opposite order.

Comment: I see you updated in response to my other notes, but do you have a response to my first or second comments?

Comment: hi, i have updated the code, but i am not sure how best to re-write the `searchFor`? in regards to (1) - no i don't want to search for `.` (2) not sure how to make it for multiple terms

Comment: I'm afraid that those didn't actually answer either question. I'm not looking for *how* but for *what*.  (1) Do you really want to search for your string across all properties?  Or would just the `name` property do?  (2) You mention a search string that happens to match across two consecutive records.  Is that important?  Or would "rat Arthur the" equally find your first record?

Comment: (1) only on the `name` property (2) yes, `rat Arthur the` should yield the first record only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helps me when approaching a functional style is to build the full spec up slowly from the most basic requirements. The requirements aren't clear but it appears you want to return an the object which matches a name, and possibly extend this functionality so that you can pass in an array of names and get an array of objects back.

So let's start with the most basic requirement, which is to return a boolean based on if the name matches the given parameter. For this we'll use the function `propEq`:

```
const nameEq = pred => R.propEq('name', pred)

// This is just a partially application of:
// const nameEq = pred => obj => R.propEq('name', pred)(obj)
```

So now to find all objects in the list that match we use the function `filter` which will return the any elements which evaluate to true for the supplied function

```
const nameInList = pred => R.filter(nameEq(pred))

// This is again a partial application of:
// const nameInList = pred => obj => R.filter(nameEq(pred))(obj)
```

This can then be called with the

```
nameInList('Arthur')(objects)
```

which returns

```
[
  {
    "duration": "0.360000",
    "name": "Arthur",
    "paragraph": "p0-0",
    "time": "0.660000"
  },
  {
    "duration": "0.360000",
    "name": "Arthur",
    "paragraph": "p1-0",
    "time": "89.820000"
  }
]
```

or we can partially apply our function

```
const findArthur = nameInList('Arthur')
```

and later pass in our list of objects

```
findArthur(objects)
```

---

We can then go even further to reverse the parameters by defining:

```
const flipped = R.compose(R.curry, R.flip(R.uncurryN(2, nameInList)))
```

This will then allow us to partially apply the function to `objects` and simply lookup names by passing in a string.